# Cannot use Eval() on Separator transformations [Hierarchical transformations]

Tags: web-parts, hierarchy, kentico

Kentico is the devil! Working with HierarchicalViewer WebParts (this is my first day attempting them). I have the following hierarchy:

- `Main Page`

  - `SubPage 1` [document includes fields: **Title**, **Intro**, **Bottom Content**]

    - `SubSubpage 1.1`
    - `SubSubpage 1.2`
    - `SubSubpage 1.3`
  - `SubPage 2` [same fields...]

    - `...`

On the `Main Page`, I want to automate a display of each `Subpage`: including `Subpage` **Title** and **Intro**, a list of all `SubSubpage`s, then `Subpage` **Bottom Content**. In other words:

### Desired output:

```html
<section>
    <h1>[Subpage 1 Title]</h1>
    <p>[Subpage 1 Intro]</p>
    <ul>
        <li>[SubSubpage 1.1 Title]</li>
        <li>[SubSubpage 1.2 Title]</li>
        <li>[SubSubpage 1.3 Title]</li>
    </ul>
    <p>[Subpage 1 Bottom Content]</p>
</section>

<section>
    <h1>[Subpage 2 Title]</h1>
    <p>[Subpage 2 Intro]</p>
    <ul>
        <li>[SubSubpage 2.1 Title]</li>
        <li>[SubSubpage 2.2 Title]</li>
        <li>[SubSubpage 2.3 Title]</li>
    </ul>
    <p>[Subpage 2 Bottom Content]</p>
</section>

...
```

Simple, right? Not for Kentico... nope, they don't do people-logic. I cant get the *Bottom Content* to show up.

### I have the following hierarchical transformations:

#### Item transformation for Level 0:

```cs
<section>
    <h1><%# Eval("Subpage Title") %></h1>
```

#### Header, Footer, and Item transformations for Level 1 (respectively):

`<ul>` | `</ul>` | `<li><%# Eval("SubSubpage Title") %></li>`

Had to specify a blank Separator transformation for Level 1 so it didn't inherit Level 0. (Why specify the separator for Level 0 only if you're going to plop in on all the other unspecified levels anyway?)

Finally,

#### Separator and Footer transformations for Level 0:

```cs
    <!-- Only works on the Footer, not the Separator:
        <%# Eval("Subpage Bottom Content") %>-->
</section>
```

(Why must I create transformation for Separator AND a Footer anyways? Why can't I just do Footer - makes the most logical sense - and it be applied to EVERY item on Level 0? I digress.)

The reason my **Bottom Content** doesn't work is because it seems you can't `Eval()` document fields on Separator transformations.

It was quite complicated to figure out and almost equally so to describe in this question. I need to know how to accomplish the desired output above using hierarchical transformations (or something else if you know of it)! I'm using Kentico 7 (unfortunately).

### Update

I only have front-end access to CMSDesk and SiteManager, and I neither have access to the back-end filesystem nor do I know ASP.NET.

Comment: Can you double check that you're using an ASCX transformation and not a Text/XML transformation?  http://imgur.com/EUVnMd0

Comment: @Jerreck, yep, all of them have ASCX transformation types: http://i.imgur.com/0dmENQZ.png. I fear I may have to go a different route... just manually enter the content instead of using a repeater. Really wish someone could shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

Took a lot of digging to figure this one out, and although I agree that Kentico's API is a mess, it looks like this is actually a limitation of ASP.NET's `<asp:repeater>` control on which Kentico's repeaters and viewers are based.

Take a look at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465889/repeaters-separatortemplate-with-eval) where someone had the same issue that you're having with the separator template of the `<asp:repeater>`.

Then, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466172/2344773) that shows a possible workaround.

I haven't been able to figure out exactly why the item separator cannot eval() data that's been bound to an asp:repeater, but [every](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx) [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.separatortemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) I find shows the item separator to be containing only plain text - no data is being resolved.

As an alternative to the hierarchical transformation, you could always try nesting repeaters and binding their data OnInit (if you have to, sometimes you don't).  It can get messy if you get too complicated with it, but it's a reliable technique.

For example, after you setup a repeater in a page template, add this to that repeater's transformation:

```
  <cms:CMSRepeater 
      ID="ControlID"
      DelayedLoading="true"
      runat="server" 
      Path="./%"
      ClassNames="custom.DocTypeName;" 
      CategoryName="" 
      MaxRelativeLevel="-1" 
      SelectTopN="0" 
      SelectOnlyPublished="true"                      
      OrderBy=""
      Columns=""
      TransformationName="custom.DocTypeName.TransformationName"
      RelationshipName="" 
      RelatedNodeIsOnTheLeftSide=""
      HideControlForZeroRows="false" 
      enableViewState="false" 
  />
  <script runat="server">
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    { 
      // an example of how to bind data OnInit
      // to get the data you need
      ControlID.WhereCondition = "NodeParentID = '"+ GetSearchValue("NodeID")+"'";  
    } 
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for digging for me. I don't know why Kentico doesn't have documentation and reasonable examples for how to use... well, most of their stuff. Been working with it for almost 3 years now and haven't been able to figure out why they do things the way they do. The only more frustrating, convoluted system to work with is Microsoft SharePoint.

Comment: I have ONLY front-end CMSDesk/SiteManager access (I should put that in the original question), so can't do any ASP stuff... I wouldn't know how even if I had server access, so I don't believe I can implement that code unless I can plop that somewhere USING the CMS. I have 7 SubPages, so I might just create 7 repeaters and not mess with hierarchy crap. But it would be nice to be able to do in case that 7 turns to 8 or 6 - so my non-technical team doesn't have to mess with it if I'm gone.

Comment: No problem.  You can use the code sample I provided in an ASCX transformation and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In this case (but not generally) the most clean and correct solution is to use a nested repeater (as Jerreck suggested).

You'll need just these two transformations; the main one:

```
<section>
  <h1><%# Eval("Title") %></h1>
  <p><%# Eval("Intro") %></p>
  <ul>
    <cms:CMSRepeater ID="repListItems" runat="server" DelayedLoading="true" 
       ClassNames="your.ClassName" TransformationName="your.NestedRepeater.TransformationID" />
  </ul>
  <p><%# Eval("BottomContent") %></p>
</section>
```

and one for subsubpages:

```
<li><%# Eval("DocumentName") %></li>
```

And of course set Nested control ID property of the web part to appropriate value. There is no further coding needed. You can find more information about using nested controls [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Using+nested+controls). Hope it'll help you.

Note: With Kentico v8+ you can specify the location in transformation (with [SubLevelPlaceHolder](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Using+hierarchical+transformations#Usinghierarchicaltransformations-Settingthelocationofsublevelsintransformations)) where sublevels should be rendered.

Comment: Re: SubLevelPlaceHolder: that's friggin' awesome. That's exactly what I was thinking would make the most sense when I was building this. We should be migrating to v8 soon this year, so I will definitely play with that. In the meantime, I will dig into nested controls when I get back to this side of the project. (I've moved on for the time being to keep my sanity and to keep my computer from going airborne.)